# Azure media services live streaming endpoint hangs in "starting" status

Tags: azure, http-live-streaming, azure-media-services

The default live streaming endpoint doesn't start and I can't stop or cancel. The only way to get out of it is to delete the entire resource group. I did it and tried again with the same results. I added 1 streaming unit and enabled the CDN before trying to start it the second time. Any idea what's the problem and/or how to make the end point start properly?

[image]

Comment: If it is still happening please contact @AzureSupport on twitter to escalate.

Answer (score 2):

@Danny F had his answer deleted, but he was right on the money.

Azure Media Service's streaming endpoints will hang on "Starting" for several minutes then stop if you've specified a CDN, but have not created the accompanying eligible CDN endpoint.

Additionally, by default, the default streaming endpoint is created with a Verizon CDN type which are not available in the "Free Trial"

To solve the problem either:

- Disable CDN

[image]

- Create an eligible CDN endpoint and reference it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Still, at the end of 2019, this issue persists (using *media services v3*). If you follow the [Azure Media Services tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/azure/media-services/latest/access-api-cli-how-to), in the last step, you are supposed to create a streaming endpoint with `default` name, however, if you start it - via a portal or via code -

```
await client.StreamingEndpoints.StartAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, DefaultStreamingEndpointName);
```

it's stucked on `Starting` status and then stopped, so your code still awaits.

I don't know the reason for this (IMO buggy) behavior, nevertheless, I've found a solution.

In the portal just go to your `Media service` > `Streaming endpoints`, add the new streaming endpoint with new name e.g. `implicit`, run it (via portal or API) and use this new one.

Comment: The reason why this works is because you bypass the default CDN behavior.  A CDN attempts to be created by default, but is not eligible in the free trial. Nice workaround! It helps explain my answer too.